# Map not getting Displayed

Tags: android

Map is not getting displayed in my app !

Layout :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity :

```
    package com.example.vogellamapsv2;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

    import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
      static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
      static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);
      private GoogleMap map;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        map = ((SupportMapFragment)     getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new     MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG).title("Hamburg"));
    Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(KIEL)
        .title("Kiel")
    .snippet("Kiel is cool")
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
        .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));

    // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HAMBURG, 15));

    // Zoom in, animating the camera.
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);

      }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    return true;
  }

}
```

Manifest :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.vogellamapsv2"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

        <uses-feature
            android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true" />

        <uses-permission android:name="com.example.vogellamapsv2.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name="com.example.vogellamapsv2.MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="AIzaSyBMXe0_OCa6HyvJO7kaP5u6-Dy3LZe3P1Y" />
             </application>

    </manifest>
```

My Problem is :

I have tested this app in the following ways in emulator and device too but map is not getting displayed !

1. I have put a key from debug certificate and,
2. I generated a certificate for my app and generated sha1 and extracted a key from google console , i have put this key too but map is not displayed !

All prerequisites like GoogleAPI target, lib project, ..etc is setup carefully !

Please answer what might be the solution ?

Comment: I guess Google Maps does not work on emulators!

Comment: I tested in real device too...

Answer (score 0):

In my android manifest I have the line:

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

I have this just after the application tag. Don't know if this will fix it but it was on the tutorial I used.